# How to get all newer files which are newer in ftp folder PHP

Tags: php

If 10 files are already in the ftp folder & 5 more new files are uploaded then i want to download all the new files ie, all new 5 files from ftp which are uploaded using PHP.

i have the code which downloads the last uploaded file, How to download all newer files?

the existing code is

```
<?php
$conn = ftp_connect('ip of ftp');
ftp_login($conn, 'useename', 'password');
$files = ftp_nlist($conn, 'GSTR1');
$mostRecent = array(
    'time' => 0,
    'file' => null
);
foreach ($files as $file) {    
    $time = ftp_mdtm($conn, $file);
    if ($time > $mostRecent['time']) {

        $mostRecent['file'] = $file;
    }
}
;
$local_file1="D:/FTP_Data/".$mostRecent['file']."";
$local_file=str_replace('/GSTR1', '', $local_file1);
echo($local_file);
$fh = fopen($local_file, 'w');
fwrite($fh," ");
$rs=ftp_get($conn, $local_file, $mostRecent['file'], FTP_ASCII);
if($rs)
{
    echo("Downloading");    
}
else
{
    echo("Something error");
}
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).